# Is there a word for 'nobody likes me' syndrome?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe ***nobody likes me*** feeling?

What would be appropriate in the following cases?

> I am suffering from ______. 
>   
>  Or 
>   I feel ______.

Comment: **Depression** could fit your needs.

Comment: Unloved/unwanted/friendless. Maybe paranoid ;)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus LOL, I think depression is more like *feeling low*.

Comment: @TokenToucan *Unloved* does seems to fit the second sentence.

Comment: ***Discrimination***: treatment or consideration of, or making a distinction in favor of or against, a person.

Comment: @Dumbledore Then can I interest you in **jerk**? "I am suffering from being a jerk." and "I feel like a jerk." All jokes aside though; are you simply asking about the feeling without relation to the cause of feeling that way?

Comment: @Dumbledore I feel like "Calimero" http://www.voiceoverherald.com/my-10000-dollar-voice-over-mistake/

Comment: "Poor baby" syndrome.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus There could be [different causes of depression](http://www.webmd.com/depression/guide/causes-depression). I'm talking about the kind of feeling you get from rejection. *I feel like a jerk* made me chuckle though ;)

Comment: @Elian I liked "Calimero". It's similar to ***the ugly duckling***, eh?

Comment: @Dumbledore What about **outcast**? *I feel like an outcast.*

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, *outcast* is one of the answers. I think it fits well.

Comment: @Dumbledore Yeah, sort of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are experiencing this feeling, you may feel like an *outcast*. Definition:

> A person who has been rejected by society or a social group.

Example:

> No longer could gays and lesbians be treated by society and by the law as *outcasts*, a marginal and disposable fringe.

The word can also function as an adjective. Example:

> The smaller child was made to feel *outcast*.

Synonyms:

> pariah, persona non grata, reject, outsider, leper, black sheep, red-headed stepchild

---

If you are experiencing this feeling, you may have low *self-esteem*. Definition:

> Confidence in one’s own worth or abilities; self-respect.

Example:

> We provide assertiveness training for those with low *self-esteem*.

---

(Oxford Dictionaries Online: [outcast](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/outcast), [self-esteem](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/self-esteem))

Answer (score 1):

> I am suffering from **paranoia**.
>   I feel **paranoid**.

Definition at [Cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paranoid)

> ​paranoid: feeling ​extremely ​nervous and ​worried because **you ​believe that other ​people do not like you** or are ​trying to ​harm you.

But when on the subject, consider ...

> "Just because you're paranoid doesn't mean they aren't after you."-Joseph Heller in Catch-22

Comment: Unfortunately  this does not get at OP’s context of feeling unwanted or unliked.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm feeling mopey, I'll mutter under my breath "**guess I'll go eat worms**", referring to the popular kids song "[Nobody Likes Me (Guess I'll Go Eat Worms)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TKQmcfTJ1GA)"

Mopey might be a good word too. [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mope):

> Be dejected and apathetic

Eyeore from Winnie the Poo is described in Wikipedia as suffering from [Anhedonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anhedonia), which is essentially the opposite of hedonism.

Answer (score 0):

> I am suffering from ***rejection***.
>
> Or
>
> I feel ***rejected***.

---

> Or
>
> I feel *like a **reject***.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely discrimination; the unjust or prejudicial treatment of different categories of people, especially on the grounds of race, age, or sex, (sexuality, social status, the people you associate with, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I don't think discrimination is a feeling, it might cause the feeling described in the question but it doesn't describe what the question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

Autophobia or monophobia, i.e., fear of being alone, can happen when around others. It's more about fear of being lonely. It can include a feeling that one is unloved or unliked by others.